# Creating nested maps with Java stream and groupingBy

Tags: java, java-stream

Given the following code:

```
  private enum TheA {
    AA,
  }

  private class TheB {
    String b;
  }

  private enum TheC {
    CC,
  }

  private class Rule {
    TheA a;
    TheB b;
    TheC c;

    public TheA getA() {
      return a;
    }

    public TheB getB() {
      return b;
    }

    public TheC getC() {
      return c;
    }
  }

  private Map<TheA, Map<TheB, Set<TheC>>> createView(Set<Rule> rules) {
    Map<TheA, Map<TheB, List<Rule>>> value =
        rules.stream().collect(groupingBy(Rule::getA, groupingBy(Rule::getB)));
    return value;
  }
```

I want the types of `createView` to type check. Currently, I am able to get the nested maps as I want but what is missing is to go from **`Set<Rule>` to `Set<TheC>`**. As an extra bonus, I would also want this whole structure to be **immutable** since it's only representing a specific view of my data.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `Collector.mapping` with `Collectors.toSet` downstream :

```
private Map<TheA, Map<TheB, Set<TheC>>> createView(Set<Rule> rules) {
    return rules.stream().collect(groupingBy(Rule::getA,
            groupingBy(Rule::getB, mapping(Rule::getC, toSet()))));
}
```